# Web Interface for History of Salt-Stack Runs

Tags: salt-stack

How can I visualize the history of old stalt-stack runs?

I found the docs how to store the job cache in an external system: [externa-job-cache](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jobs/external_cache.html#external-master-cache), but how to get a simple web interface?

My goal: I want to answer questions like "What did salt do on host "foo" on day 2015-12-24?"

Answer (score 2):

There is [Lothiraldan/saltpad](https://github.com/Lothiraldan/saltpad) which might fit your needs.

Be aware - it was completely rewritten a short time ago and the [new version is not ready](https://github.com/Lothiraldan/saltpad/issues/127) to be used with the stable version of salt. The [old version](https://github.com/tinyclues/saltpad/tree/saltpad_v1) might fit your needs right now.

As far as i can remember it did **not** show you the results of all jobs executed on the salt-master, but of those executed using saltpad itself.

If saltpad did not fit your needs it should be possible with a little effort to just solve your requirements using the REST API salt provides. Have a look at this [REST URI](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html#jobs).

Answer (score 0):

This may be too simple, but if your queries are always about host "foo", then you can get this info from the minion log, provided you set the loglevel to info (warning is the default).  If you have access to the minions, you can search there:

```
# grep -v DEBUG /var/log/salt/minion | grep -v utils.schedule | grep -v salt.loaded.int.module | grep -v salt.fileclient | grep 2016-03-13
2016-03-13 03:42:26,347 [salt.minion      ][INFO    ][16771] User root Executing command state.highstate with jid 20160313034226341724
2016-03-13 03:42:26,371 [salt.minion      ][INFO    ][17877] Starting a new job with PID 17877
2016-03-13 03:42:27,688 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Loading fresh modules for state activity
2016-03-13 03:42:28,438 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Loading fresh modules for state activity
2016-03-13 03:42:28,712 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Loading fresh modules for state activity
2016-03-13 03:42:29,181 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [/etc/yum.repos.d/bak] at time 03:42:29.180461
2016-03-13 03:42:29,181 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state file.directory for /etc/yum.repos.d/bak
2016-03-13 03:42:29,183 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] The directory /etc/yum.repos.d/bak is in the correct state
2016-03-13 03:42:29,189 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [/etc/yum.repos.d/bak] at time 03:42:29.183182
2016-03-13 03:42:29,287 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [devops-20160304T0944-centos-7-salt] at time 03:42:29.286499
2016-03-13 03:42:29,287 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state pkgrepo.managed for devops-20160304T0944-centos-7-salt
2016-03-13 03:42:29,295 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Package repo 'devops-20160304T0944-centos-7-salt' already configured
2016-03-13 03:42:29,295 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [devops-20160304T0944-centos-7-salt] at time 03:42:29.295372
2016-03-13 03:42:29,804 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [salt-minion] at time 03:42:29.804021
2016-03-13 03:42:29,804 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state pkg.installed for salt-minion
2016-03-13 03:42:30,326 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Package salt-minion is already installed
2016-03-13 03:42:30,327 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [salt-minion] at time 03:42:30.326808
2016-03-13 03:42:30,327 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [/etc/salt/minion] at time 03:42:30.327101
2016-03-13 03:42:30,328 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state file.managed for /etc/salt/minion
2016-03-13 03:42:30,344 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] The file /etc/salt/minion is in the correct state
2016-03-13 03:42:30,345 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [/etc/salt/minion] at time 03:42:30.344459
2016-03-13 03:42:30,346 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [salt-minion] at time 03:42:30.345981
2016-03-13 03:42:30,346 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state service.running for salt-minion
2016-03-13 03:42:30,506 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] The service salt-minion is already running
2016-03-13 03:42:30,507 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [salt-minion] at time 03:42:30.506926
2016-03-13 03:42:30,507 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [ntp] at time 03:42:30.507251
2016-03-13 03:42:30,508 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state pkg.installed for ntp
2016-03-13 03:42:30,508 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Package ntp is already installed
2016-03-13 03:42:30,508 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [ntp] at time 03:42:30.508308
2016-03-13 03:42:30,509 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [ntpdate] at time 03:42:30.508561
2016-03-13 03:42:30,509 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state pkg.installed for ntpdate
2016-03-13 03:42:30,509 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Package ntpdate is already installed
2016-03-13 03:42:30,509 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [ntpdate] at time 03:42:30.509431
2016-03-13 03:42:30,512 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [/etc/ntp.conf] at time 03:42:30.511811
2016-03-13 03:42:30,539 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [/etc/ntp.conf] at time 03:42:30.538741
2016-03-13 03:42:30,539 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state file.managed for /etc/ntp.conf
2016-03-13 03:42:30,563 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] The file /etc/ntp.conf is in the correct state
2016-03-13 03:42:30,563 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [/etc/ntp.conf] at time 03:42:30.563260
2016-03-13 03:42:30,564 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [/etc/ntp/step-tickers] at time 03:42:30.563540
2016-03-13 03:42:30,564 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state file.absent for /etc/ntp/step-tickers
2016-03-13 03:42:30,564 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] File /etc/ntp/step-tickers is not present
2016-03-13 03:42:30,564 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [/etc/ntp/step-tickers] at time 03:42:30.564369
2016-03-13 03:42:30,566 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [ntpdate] at time 03:42:30.565970
2016-03-13 03:42:30,566 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state service.running for ntpdate
2016-03-13 03:42:30,707 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] The service ntpdate is already running
2016-03-13 03:42:30,707 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [ntpdate] at time 03:42:30.707253
2016-03-13 03:42:30,708 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [ntpd] at time 03:42:30.707981
2016-03-13 03:42:30,708 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state service.running for ntpd
2016-03-13 03:42:30,852 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] The service ntpd is already running
2016-03-13 03:42:30,852 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [ntpd] at time 03:42:30.852311
2016-03-13 03:42:30,853 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Running state [exec 0>&- # close stdin
2016-03-13 03:42:30,854 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Executing state cmd.wait for exec 0>&- # close stdin
2016-03-13 03:42:30,854 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] No changes made for exec 0>&- # close stdin
2016-03-13 03:42:30,854 [salt.state       ][INFO    ][17877] Completed state [exec 0>&- # close stdin
2016-03-13 03:42:30,855 [salt.minion      ][INFO    ][17877] Returning information for job: 20160313034226341724
```

But, yeah, if you want to do something with better search, then an external job cache is the right thing.  We're going to forward job results to elastic search, but I haven't played with that yet.

Comment: Yes, looking at the logs would be a solution. A nice web interface is what I was looking for. I personally prefer a relational database model to elastic search. But maybe this is my FUD.